# Open Office for doc, docx and rtf to html conversion

Tags: php, html, linux, openoffice.org

How can i read formatted text as HTML from doc, docs and rtf files?

My script is on LAMP, can access openoffice installed on server for this type of conversion?

**EDIT**

Its not necessary that i want to access openoffice through a php extension or Apache module, if it is possible to use it using cli trhoug php, it would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Puno: http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05

> This project is a PHP5 module written in C++ that brings the OpenOffice.org UNO Programming API to the PHP userspace.

It uses UNO Reflection API by OpenOffice for it. It's easy to start with. Check out sample example given there.

Comment: Thanks @ksg91 for you response, i will go through it once i am sure that i need this solution. Need to research on other possibilities.

Comment: Its hard and long process but i am in to it.